# Image generation from spreadsheet data

Tags: php, javascript, images

I work in retail. For promo sales we're given a spreadsheet with data containing the information about the product and its prices. With this data we're supposed to create sale tags. More specifically, the data to be displayed includes the product name, short description, sale price, normal price, amount saved, etc.

Is there a programmatic way I can convert this spreadsheet data to a nice sale tag in one click? Here are some rough ideas of mine:

- PHP image generation of a html page which is then converted to PDF (since I know PHP)
- Same as above but with javascript
- Somehow link google spreadsheets (or MS excel) with google docs (or MS word) for document generation

I'd rather but am not restricted to a web-based solution. Otherwise, I'm open to the quickest/easiest method to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft word mail-merge with the excel sheet as database is perfect for this use case.

Make a page in word with all the elements n design. Then from Mail Merge menu, add the variable data, like Date, Price etc.In the end, merge, and then print on paper or as pdf.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), with this you can read the data contained in the excel file, with the data read you can do multiple things...

- Use a graphical library like [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) to construct an image file
- Or create an HTML template for the tag and then use [DOM PDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) to create the pdf file in one stroke
- Or both of the above at the same time

Also, at this point I have mention that the Macros in MS Excel are powerful enough to do this.